# Checking the Lindeberg Condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\mathbb P(X_n=\pm 1)=\frac 14$, $\mathbb P(X_n=\pm n)=\frac 1{4n^2}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=0)=\frac 12 - \frac 1{2n^2}$ for all $n\ge 1$. Define the triangular array $\{X_{nj}:1\le j\le n\}_{n\ge 1}$ by setting $X_{nj}=\frac{X_j}{\sqrt n}$. Check whether the above triangular array satisfies the Lindeberg condition.

I have calculated
$$s_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{X_j}{\sqrt n}$$
and
$$\sigma_{nj}^2:=\mathbb E[X_{nj}^2]=\frac 1n$$
and hence
$$S_n^2:=\sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_{nj}^2 = 1$$
So, I need to prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2\mathbf{1}_{|X_i|>\epsilon}]\to 0\;\; \forall \epsilon>0$$
to check the Lindeberg condition.
which is clearly false as the expression is a sum.

I must have made some mistake somewhere which I can't figure out. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$The Lindeberg-Feller condition:

> If $(r_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of naturals, for every $n\in\Bbb N$ independent random variables $(X_{n,j})_{j=1}^n$ are given all with zero expectation and each having nonzero standard deviation $\sigma_{n,j}$, define for all $n\in\Bbb N$: $$\sigma_n:=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{r_n}\sigma^2_{n,j}}$$
>
> Then we say the Lindeberg-Feller condition is satisfied if for all $\epsilon>0$: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma^2_n}\sum_{j=1}^{r_n}\E[X^2_{n,j}\chi_{|X_{n,j}|\ge\epsilon\sigma_n}]=0$$

I really don’t know what you mean when you say “which is clearly false as the expression is a sum”.

By my calculations, $\sigma_{n,j}=n^{-1/2}$ is always true and I agree that $\sigma_n=1$ too. In this situation we are taking $r_n:=n$.

So we have to check: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\E[X_{n,j}^2\chi_{|X_{n,j}|\ge\epsilon}]=0$$For any $\epsilon>0$. You seem to have missed out the $(n,j)$ subscripts. That’s the same thing as saying: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\E[X_j^2\chi_{|X_j|\ge\epsilon\sqrt{n}}]=0$$

Fixing $0<\epsilon<1$, whenever $n>\epsilon^{-2}$ we know $|X_j|\ge\epsilon\sqrt{n}$ is plausible only on the events $X_j=\pm j$. The expectation then becomes $j^2\cdot(1/4j^2)\cdot2=1/2$... *if* it is also true that $j\ge\epsilon\sqrt{n}$. So for suitably large $n$ the expression is: $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=\lceil\epsilon\sqrt{n}\rceil}^n(1/2)=\frac{1}{2n}(n-\lfloor\epsilon\sqrt{n}\rfloor)=\frac{1}{2}-\mathcal{O}(1/\sqrt{n})$$

It is now clear that the Lindeberg-Feller condition does *not* hold.

Comment: Great answer, thanks (+1)!

Comment: @SayanDutta You're welcome